# How to stop a timer and start it again with a different task?

Tags: java, button, timer, timertask

I want a timer task to start when i click on a button... when i click on the button again the code should stop the task and start again with a diffrent value(coffeeMakerPoint). Please help me I'm a beginner

here is my code

```
 private void coffeeMakerMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         


    java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
{
        public void run() {
            cScore = cScore + coffeeMakerPoint;
            tScore= tScore + coffeeMakerPoint;
            currentScoreLBL.setText("Current Score " + cScore );
            totalScoreLBL.setText("Total Score "+ tScore);
        }   

}, 1, 2000);
```

Comment: Beginners too can look for documentation, read it, and discover that a Timer has a cancel() method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: You need to define the timer variable outside the click listener (as instance var), so you can refer to the same instance on every click. Then you can cancel the Timer as Gimby sais.

Comment: thanks but I knew there was timer cancel method and i did try it with my code with if condition (timer part in if condition and cancel method in else part) but it didn't work :|